# Can't create Configurable Product with attribute error

Tags: configurable-product

When I try to add Configurable product

I got this error

> Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To
>   Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available.

I check the attribute set and remove all attribute except system attribute

but I still got error. I check description attribute it's textfield type

Description attribute only textfield is needed

I'm confusing how to create configurable product .. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Magento, if you want to create  a configurable product then  you need first create an attribute:

1. `Scope: should Global`
2. `Type: Dropdown`
3. `Use To Create Configurable make it yes.`

Then you need assign this attribute to attribute set

[image]

Comment: Ah I need to add at least one attribute for that instead of I have to all all attribute that kind I got it thanks!

Comment: [Image credit](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/63497/14992)

Comment: I don't see the "Use to Create Configurable Product" option on mine. Magento 1.9.2.1

Comment: I will check and let u kniw tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

You select scope as 'Global', input type as 'drop down' , So can see 'Use To Create Configurable ' .

Comment: The user already try this, add answer which help to solve problem.