# Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

I get the following error when trying to make a configurable product on Magento 1.9

Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available.

I've tried this already, but it isn't working :S
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the bug is that only those attributes show up? Only global dropdown attributes can be configurable options. If the problem is they're not showing up for configurable products then make sure that you've added it to the appropriate attribute set and reindexed afterwards.

Comment: Where's the error?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are creating your attribute correctly, add some options to it. Once your attribute is complete, you need to add it to the attribute set by going here: Catalog > Attributes > Manage attribute sets. Once there add your attribute to the attribute set:

[image]

Once you do that, you may need to re-index. Now you can create a configurable product, go to Catalog > Manage Products then select "Add a Product" on the New Product screen select your attribute set, and select "Configurable Product" front the Product Type drop down list. When you click continue you should see your attribute as a checkbox:

[image]

Select your attribute and proceed to create your product like any other product.
Hope this helps.